# Calling a Java static method with generics from Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java method of the form

```
    public interface JavaInterface< T extends A >{
        static < T extends A > JavaInterface< T > callThis(){
         //I want to call this in scala

        }
    }
```

In Scala I write

```
val x = JavaInterface[SomeClass].callThis()
```

but I get an error telling me it "is not a value". How do I call that static method in Scala?

Comment: You suppose to have static methods in the companion object which will be available for you like in Java. ClassName.methodname

Comment: I think he wants to call that Java method from Scala code. Please provide a full example of what you're doing, including the full error message you're getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want:

```
val x = JavaInterface.callThis[SomeClass]()
```

It's the method, not the type, that's parameterised for static methods.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have now assumes `JavaInterface` is an object with a nilary `apply` method that returns another object with a `callThis()` method. For that, your code would have to look something like this (in Scala):

```
trait JavaInterface[T] {
  def callThis() = println("foobar")
}

object JavaInterface {
  def apply[T <: JavaInterface[T]] = new JavaInterface[T] {}
}
```

Since you are calling the `callThis` method on `JavaInterface`, you need to do `JavaInterface.callThis[SomeClass]()` instead, giving the type parameter to the method instead of the object (or Java interface) you're calling it on.